# Django filter model by it's related model list

Tags: python, django-models

There is purchase orders which contains n+1 products.
I want to filter PurchaseOrder by products in it.
In search process for looking up PurschaseOrders query set should return all purchase orders where there are itemA and itemB in it.

Modell classes

```
class PurchaseOrder:
    id = ....

class Product:
    purchase_order = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, related_name='product')
```

For lookup as input values I have list of Product id's, for example lets take q = [1,3,5]

As result I need all Purchase orders, which contains product1, prodcut2, product3.

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't return any result.

```
   q_objects = (Q(product__in=query[0]), Q(product__in=query[1]))
   qs = self.filter(q_objects)
```

As additional solution, which is not done in the code, because in opinion can cost a lot of resources:
1.return query of purchase orders, which contain product1.
Looping trough again, this time checking if Purchase orders contain product2, then keep for further validation. And keep the process with product all ids, from list.

2. by using django signals, which on each save signal, saves all product id's comma separated in text field. Which is compared with q

This currently is first level of implementation. Later it would be necessary to filter also by count.
For example if q =[1,1,3,5] will return all products, where there are two products1 and one for each product3 and product5.

Comment: So these should contain *all* products ids, or *any*?

Comment: It should contain all products ids from q list

Comment: how can a product be added twice (or more) to the `PurchaseOrder`? It has a `ForeignKey`, hence each `Product` is related to (at most) one `PurchaseOrder`.

Comment: It doesn't restrict You to create one more `Product` with ForeignKey to the same `PurchaseOrder`

Comment: no indeed, an order can have *multiple* products, but not the same product multiple times, nor the same product for multiple orders. This will thus introduce some "duplication logic".

Comment: Agree. Actual business case is different, but analogy with products/orders are simpler to explain. Why I allow duplication? Because in further implementation product sequence will be important for me and then I will use reference to prodcut, for example. product1: locationA prdouct1:locationB, product2:locationC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

ids = [1, 3, 5]
PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(product_id__in=qs).alias(
    nproducts=Count('product')
).filter(nproducts=len(set(ids)))
```